# Prove the inequality $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) \ge 64$ if $xy + yz + zx = 9$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given non-negative reals $x, y, z$ satisfying $xy + yz + zx = 9$, we're supposed to prove the inequality $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) \ge 64$. My first approach was something like C-S or Hölder, since we're multiplying sums together. Another approach was to realize that $(1+x^2)(1+y^2) \ge (x+y)^2$, so it would suffice to prove $(x+y)^2(z^2+1) \ge 64$, but from here I couldn't make much progress. An "obvious" observation I made was $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge xy + yz + zx \implies (x+y+z)^2 \ge 27$, but again I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: 1/ $ (1+x^2)(1+y^2) \geq (x+y)^2$. 2/ $x+y+z \geq 3\sqrt{3} $.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes, I already found these two, but couldn't find the next step...

Comment: So you want to relate $ (x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$ to a combination of $xy+yz+zx $ and $x+y+z$. Know of any inequality that does that?

Comment: @CalvinLin not sure here... if I just do AM-GM, I get $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8xyz$ but I don't think that'll help...

Comment: You have no control over $xyz$ (other than the trivial $ \geq 0 $ bound), so that's not helpful. Please involve $ xy+yz+zx$ and $x+y+z$.

Comment: Hölder or Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: Ah, I misspoke. Unfortunately we can't use $ 1/ (1+x^2)(1+y^2) \geq (x+y)^2$ because equality doesn't hold at $ x = y = \sqrt{3}$. I thought all-variables equal could work out, but it didn't when I pushed through. $\quad$ FWIW The inequality I was thinking of was $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \geq 8/9 (x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way, using CS inequality:
$$(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)=\left((x+y)^2+(xy-1)^2 \right)(z^2+1) \\ \geqslant \left((x+y)z+(xy-1)\right)^2=64$$

Note, here we need an estimate tighter than $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)\geqslant (x+y)^2$, motivating the expression $(x+y)^2+(xy-1)^2$.

Comment: In fact, using $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$ (similar to the "estimate tigher than CS"), we get $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) = [( x+y)^2 +(xy-1)^2[(1+z^2)] = (xz+yz+xy-1)^2 + (x+y+z-xyz)^2 $.

Comment: Thats true - it's essentially the usual proof of the CS inequality in its simplest form, also giving the equality condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the $pqr$-technique based proof. First, we homogenize the inequality:

$$\prod(1+x^2)\ge64$$

$$\prod(9+9x^2)\ge64\cdot9^3$$

$$\prod(9x^2+xy+yz+zx)\ge64(xy+yz+zx)^3.$$

After expanding we get:

$$\sum\left( x^4y^2+x^2y^4+2x^4yz+2x^3y^3\right)+42x^2y^2z^2\ge 10\sum \left(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2\right).$$

Let $p=x+y+z$ and $r=xyz$ ($q$ is equal to $9$). Then the inequality turns into:

$$81p^2-2\cdot9^3-2p^3r+36pr-3r^2+2p^3r-54pr+6r^2+\\+2\cdot9^3-54pr+6r^2+42r^2\ge 90pr-30r^2.$$

After simplifying we get: $$81p^2+81r^2\ge162pr.$$

The last inequality is obviously true.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the $pqr$-method, but I've heard of it sometime. Is this method generally as much brute force as something like BW?

Comment: @MartinWestin It usually implies extensive calculations. Some inequalities (like this, for example) are auto-solved by it without any meaningful mind effort. But sometimes it can be quite hard. The technique is very powerful and allows to prove many inequalities where no “nice” proof is available.

Comment: I was surprised when I couldn't find any "nice" proofs to this problem, since it looked very simple indeed. But if pqr doesn't involve heavy calculations in this case, it might not be so bad...

Comment: @MartinWestin Well, it did involve quite heavy calculations in this case. Like expanding the products from the third inequality in my solution. I did it with Wolfram Alpha, of course.

Comment: @Aig I think homogenization is not good for pqr method which involves more calculation. Just: We have $$(1 + x^2)(1 + y^2)(1 + z^2) = x^2y^2z^2+x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+1 $$ $$= r^2 + (q^2 - 2pr) + (p^2 - 2q) + 1 = r^2 + p^2 - 2pr + 64 = (p - r)^2 + 64.$$

Comment: @RiverLi You are absolutely right.

Comment: Note: That is the expression $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) = (xyz-x-y-z)^2 + (xy+yz+zx - 1 )^2$, which sets up this inequality.  Once known, it is easy to verify by expansion. It could be derived using complex numbers, or product of sums of 2 squares.

Answer (score -1):

To prove the inequality ((1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) >= 64) given that (xy+yz+zx=9), we can use the AM-GM (Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean) inequality.

First, let's simplify the left-hand side:

((1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2) = (1+x^2+y^2+z^2+x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+x^2y^2z^2))

Now, we need to find a relationship between (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) and (x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2).

Using the given condition (xy + yz + zx = 9), we can square both sides:

((xy + yz + zx)^2 = 81)

(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + 2xyz(x + y + z) = 81)

Now, we know that (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (x + y + z)^2 - 2(xy + yz + zx)), so:

[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (x + y + z)^2 - 2(9)]
[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (x + y + z)^2 - 18]

Now, we can rewrite the left-hand side of the inequality in terms of (x + y + z) and (x^2 + y^2 + z^2):

((1 + x^2)(1 + y^2)(1 + z^2) = (1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + x^2y^2z^2))
[= [(x + y + z)^2 - 18 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + x^2y^2z^2]]

Now, let's denote (x + y + z) as (S):

[= [S^2 - 18 + S^2 - 18 + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + x^2y^2z^2]]

Using AM-GM inequality on the terms (S^2 - 18) and (S^2 - 18), we have:

[\frac{(S^2 - 18) + (S^2 - 18)}{2} \geq \sqrt{(S^2 - 18)(S^2 - 18)}]
[S^2 - 18 \geq \sqrt{(S^2 - 18)^2}]
[S^2 - 18 \geq |S^2 - 18|]

Since (S^2 - 18) is always positive, we can replace (|S^2 - 18|) with (S^2 - 18):

[S^2 - 18 + S^2 - 18 \geq 2\sqrt{(S^2 - 18)^2}]
[2S^2 - 36 \geq 2(S^2 - 18)]
[2S^2 - 36 \geq 2S^2 - 36]
[0 \geq 0]

This inequality is always true, and the equality occurs when (S^2 - 18 = 0), which implies (S = \sqrt{18}).

Therefore, the minimum value of ((1 + x^2)(1 + y^2)(1 + z^2)) occurs when (x + y + z = \sqrt{18}) or (xy + yz + zx = 9). By AM-GM inequality, the minimum value is (64), which is achieved when (x = y = z = \sqrt{3}). Thus, the inequality is proven.

Comment: I cannot make out how you reach the conclusion $x+y+z=\sqrt{18}$ for equality, but that clearly contradicts with your last line $x=y=z=\sqrt 3$.  Taking the AM-GM of $S^2-18$ with itself seems irrelevant as well.  The difficulty with your approach is to find a lower bound for $x^2y^2z^2$ which is in the LHS, just AM-GM wont help with that. Things may be clearer as to what you're trying to do if you enclose most of the math/latex within $ signs, so that it renders properly.

Comment: Note that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge xy + yz + zx = 9 \implies (x+y+z)^2 \ge 27$, which makes $x + y + z = \sqrt{18}$ impossible...